# Identity matrix “ construct “

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure if the tags I added are the right ones ... correct me if I'm wrong
name of course I study is Computer Programming.

I have solved all the homework problems. This is the last question I didn't understand.
Construct the matrix

$$B=\pmatrix{     1   &     2   &      3\\
                  4     &  2    &    6\\ 
                          -3  &    -1  &     -3\\
}$$

Show that $B \times B \times B$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix and find the scalar.

I don't need you to give me an answer, help me understand how to solve it.
Thanks

Edit:
I am sorry I think I didn't make it clear ..  I am solving the homework on R program.. how to write the answer?  How can I enter the matrix on the program so I can multiply it ?

Comment: I don't get your matrix. Is it perhaps
$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\4&2&6\\-3&-1&-3\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Do you know the matrix multiplication ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 2):

You just have to multiply B by itself 3 times. You will find the result to be a diagonal Matrix equal to a scalar multiplied by the identity matrix.

So basically you need to find a scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies

$B(BB) = \begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&a\\ \end{pmatrix} $

Answer (score 0):

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\4&2&6\\-3&-1&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B\times B = \begin{pmatrix} 0&3&6\\-6&6&6\\2&-5&-6\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B\times B \times B = \begin{pmatrix} -6&0&0\\0&-6&0\\0&0&-6\end{pmatrix}= -6 I$$

Answer (score 0):

$$B^2=B \times B=\pmatrix{     1   &     2   &      3\\
                  4     &  2    &    6\\ 
                          -3  &    -1  &     -3\\
}\pmatrix{     1   &     2   &      3\\
                  4     &  2    &    6\\ 
                          -3  &    -1  &     -3\\
}=\pmatrix{     0  &     3   &      6\\
                  -6     &  6    &    6\\ 
                          2  &    -5  &     -6\\
}$$
$$B \times B^2=\pmatrix{     1   &     2   &      3\\
                  4     &  2    &    6\\ 
                          -3  &    -1  &     -3\\
}\pmatrix{     0  &     3   &      6\\
                  -6     &  6    &    6\\ 
                          2  &    -5  &     -6\\
}=\pmatrix{     -6  &     0   &      0\\
                       0&  -6    &    0\\ 
                          0  &    0 &     -6\\}=-6 \times I_3$$